# Issues with Bandwidth Usage using PhP/MySQL/Drupal

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I am hosting a site on a buddy's server. It is using MySQL, PhP and Druapl. He is complaining that it is using up all his bandwidth but for the life of me I can't figure out why. There is not image/video hosting and I believe he has ~60 GB/month. Almost all the bandwidth would be used by databases. I think the problem lies in one of the two following areas.

1)Every 3 hours do the following (via Cron):

```
For every user (~400) do:
 Get user ID from table
 Get nickname based on ID from table
 Construct URL for XML Requester using nickname
 Using CURL store the contents of URL in string (8,000 characters)
 Convert to object (200 or so properties/fields)
 Store Fields in Database (update if exists, insert otherwise) [This table has ~80,000 (400x200) rows and 3 columns - User, Stat Name, Value]
```

I guessed this uses ~3 MB per time ran (8,000*400=3,200,00 bytes = 3.2MB) and that's only 24 or so megs a day, which is nothing.

2) Request on Table with ~80,000 rows
Page allows users to select one of the 200 or so Stat Names and it will create a sorted list of that stat.
My question here is if you pass a query to server [select * from table where stat_name="blah"sort by value desc] or such does this use a lot of bandwidth or just server resources (CPU)? Table is indexed btw.

Any help/suggestions/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Example Contents of XML Requester Page:

```
<player_stats aid="25">
<stat name="nickname">S2Moebiwan</stat>
<stat name="acc_games_played">56</stat>
<stat name="acc_wins">26</stat>
<stat name="acc_losses">30</stat>
<stat name="acc_concedes">14</stat>
<stat name="acc_concedevotes">4</stat>
<stat name="acc_buybacks">15</stat>
<stat name="acc_discos">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_kicked">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_pub_skill">1525</stat>
<stat name="acc_pub_count">56</stat>
<stat name="acc_pub_pset">1</stat>
<stat name="acc_avg_score">0.00</stat>
<stat name="acc_herokills">360</stat>
<stat name="acc_herodmg">830726</stat>
<stat name="acc_heroexp">430859</stat>
<stat name="acc_herokillsgold">99989</stat>
<stat name="acc_heroassists">568</stat>
<stat name="acc_deaths">321</stat>
<stat name="acc_goldlost2death">118770</stat>
<stat name="acc_secs_dead">17551</stat>
<stat name="acc_teamcreepkills">6187</stat>
<stat name="acc_teamcreepdmg">3343661</stat>
<stat name="acc_teamcreepexp">517995</stat>
<stat name="acc_teamcreepgold">239674</stat>
<stat name="acc_neutralcreepkills">639</stat>
<stat name="acc_neutralcreepdmg">467881</stat>
<stat name="acc_neutralcreepexp">43035</stat>
<stat name="acc_neutralcreepgold">26940</stat>
<stat name="acc_bdmg">75237</stat>
<stat name="acc_bdmgexp">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_razed">54</stat>
<stat name="acc_bgold">99171</stat>
<stat name="acc_denies">346</stat>
<stat name="acc_exp_denied">15424</stat>
<stat name="acc_gold">469389</stat>
<stat name="acc_gold_spent">550152</stat>
<stat name="acc_exp">996135</stat>
<stat name="acc_actions">315974</stat>
<stat name="acc_secs">159980</stat>
<stat name="acc_consumables">739</stat>
<stat name="acc_wards">83</stat>
<stat name="acc_em_played">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_time_earning_exp">85393</stat>
<stat name="AR">0</stat>
<stat name="AREM">0</stat>
<stat name="AP">0</stat>
<stat name="APEM">0</stat>
<stat name="level">6</stat>
<stat name="total_discos">0</stat>
<stat name="total_possible_discos">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_games_played">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_wins">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_losses">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_concedes">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_concedevotes">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_buybacks">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_discos">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_kicked">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_amm_solo_rating">1500.00</stat>
<stat name="rnk_amm_solo_count">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_amm_solo_conf">0.00</stat>
<stat name="rnk_amm_solo_prov">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_amm_solo_pset">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_amm_team_rating">1500.00</stat>
<stat name="rnk_amm_team_count">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_amm_team_conf">0.00</stat>
<stat name="rnk_amm_team_prov">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_amm_team_pset">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_herokills">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_herodmg">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_heroexp">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_herokillsgold">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_heroassists">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_deaths">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_goldlost2death">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_secs_dead">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_teamcreepkills">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_teamcreepdmg">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_teamcreepexp">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_teamcreepgold">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_neutralcreepkills">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_neutralcreepdmg">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_neutralcreepexp">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_neutralcreepgold">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_bdmg">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_bdmgexp">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_razed">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_bgold">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_denies">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_exp_denied">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_gold">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_gold_spent">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_exp">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_actions">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_secs">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_consumables">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_wards">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_em_played">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_level">1</stat>
<stat name="rnk_time_earning_exp">0</stat>
</player_stats>
−
<player_stats aid="28">
<stat name="nickname">S2KingKtulu</stat>
<stat name="acc_games_played">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_wins">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_losses">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_concedes">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_concedevotes">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_buybacks">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_discos">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_kicked">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_pub_skill">1500</stat>
<stat name="acc_pub_count">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_pub_pset">1</stat>
<stat name="acc_avg_score">0.00</stat>
<stat name="acc_herokills">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_herodmg">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_heroexp">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_herokillsgold">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_heroassists">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_deaths">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_goldlost2death">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_secs_dead">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_teamcreepkills">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_teamcreepdmg">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_teamcreepexp">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_teamcreepgold">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_neutralcreepkills">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_neutralcreepdmg">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_neutralcreepexp">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_neutralcreepgold">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_bdmg">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_bdmgexp">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_razed">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_bgold">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_denies">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_exp_denied">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_gold">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_gold_spent">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_exp">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_actions">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_secs">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_consumables">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_wards">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_em_played">0</stat>
<stat name="acc_time_earning_exp">0</stat>
<stat name="AR">0</stat>
<stat name="AREM">0</stat>
<stat name="AP">0</stat>
<stat name="APEM">0</stat>
<stat name="level">1</stat>
<stat name="total_discos">0</stat>
<stat name="total_possible_discos">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_games_played">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_wins">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_losses">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_concedes">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_concedevotes">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_buybacks">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_discos">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_kicked">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_amm_solo_rating">1350.00</stat>
<stat name="rnk_amm_solo_count">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_amm_solo_conf">0.00</stat>
<stat name="rnk_amm_solo_prov">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_amm_solo_pset">1</stat>
<stat name="rnk_amm_team_rating">1500.00</stat>
<stat name="rnk_amm_team_count">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_amm_team_conf">0.00</stat>
<stat name="rnk_amm_team_prov">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_amm_team_pset">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_herokills">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_herodmg">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_heroexp">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_herokillsgold">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_heroassists">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_deaths">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_goldlost2death">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_secs_dead">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_teamcreepkills">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_teamcreepdmg">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_teamcreepexp">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_teamcreepgold">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_neutralcreepkills">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_neutralcreepdmg">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_neutralcreepexp">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_neutralcreepgold">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_bdmg">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_bdmgexp">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_razed">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_bgold">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_denies">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_exp_denied">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_gold">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_gold_spent">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_exp">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_actions">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_secs">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_consumables">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_wards">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_em_played">0</stat>
<stat name="rnk_level">1</stat>
<stat name="rnk_time_earning_exp">0</stat>
</player_stats>
</stats>
</xmlRequest>
```

Comment: Where does the network part come in? Are you accessing the MySQL server over the network, it's not on the local host? Normally using a database has nothing to do with the external network and therefore uses no bandwidth. It's just like reading a file from a disk.

Comment: My buddy is hosting the site, PhP, and MySQL all on the same server.

Comment: Have you looked at the web server logs? I once had a hacked site that was generating massive traffic from search engines, and realised because of the bandwidth consumption spike.

Comment: Where would they be located. Still new to the whole idea of optimizing/debugging web traffic. I remember someone mentioning not too long ago that google had us indexed. Is that what you mean? Sorry for the lack of experience.

Comment: So what is a good way of finding out what exactly is using so much bandwidth?

Comment: Use AWStats or other log analyzer to analyze apache logs

Comment: If it's your buddies server, I would have thought that he would be able to tell you what kind of traffic and exactly how much your site is generating? Is your buddies 60GB/month limit a download or an upload limit, or both?

Comment: It's combined. I'm having a hard time getting a hold of him but when I get more information I'll add it here. But from the code I described (that is the main traffic point on the site imo, everything else is small like forums and such) do you think it's that my code isn't very well coded or optimized or something else?

Comment: From guy who runs site
Hey,

Turned it on again. When I turned it off my logs were reading about
200 - 250MB / hour of upstream traffic, which is my pipe max.  I'm
honestly not sure what was causing the massive amounts of streaming;
normally it doesn't do that. I don't think it'd be the stats, but I could be wrong. It
was traffic coming from the site to the net, not the other way around.
I honestly don't give a damn about downstream, I have like 2gb/hour of
that and barely touch it.

Comment: Sorry, when I was querying download/upload limit I was wondering whether it was some kind of home server - obviously not. So, "traffic coming from the site to the net", the same direction as regular visitor traffic to your site? Can you account for visitor traffic? When you say, "turned it off", are you referring just to your script, or literally the whole site?! Is your script completing? Is the time period really 3 hours and not 3 minutes or something silly (but even that is _only_ 60MB/hr by your calculation)?!

Comment: I assume he meant the same direction as regular visitor traffic to the site. I'm looking at the Drupal Logs and I don't see that much access from non-registered users. By turn it off, he meant the whole site. Yes, the script completes fine. Yes, the time period is really 3 hours. I checked when cron has ran and its fine. Like I mentioned before someone mentioned something about search engines generating a lot of traffic? How would I check this?

Comment: So just finished talking with the guy who hosts it. He says that while my site was running it was near his upload cap (200-250mb/hr). When he shut it down dropped down to near 0 (He hosts multiple sites). He turned it back on and for now the bandwidth looks okay. We're guessing the issue was somebody maybe uploaded a small image file (~.5mb) as a signature or such on the forums. And then someone else linked to the image hosted on our server on a more popular site. This site would be accessed a lot (~400x per hour) which is about 200 mb/hr. Any way to stop people from doing this?

Comment: Tell your friend to get AWStats **NOW**. It tells you exactly which files are getting hammered the most, and if it indeed was a hotlinking issue then you would have known about it immediately. Your admin/friend is borderline incompetent.

Comment: I'll tell him to get AWStats. But I can't complain too much since he hosts this all for free. :)

Comment: "small image file (~.5mb)" - For the web, that is a large file. For a signature that is an enormous file! Either your script should be preventing files of that size being uploaded in the first place, or your script needs to process the uploaded image and generate another image to be used in the signature, and delete the original - may be do this anyway. You can prevent other sites from linking to your images (ie. hotlinking) by checking the referrer in requests for image files in .htaccess. I'm sure a search on "prevent image hotlinking" should find what you need for this (it's a quick fix).

Answer (score 0):

Look at your access log and add the external server IP in your baned list